# Question about functions and returns in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I am trying to create a function that converts celcius to fahrenheit and vice versa using a return statement inside. I'm confused why the code below won't return or log anything on the console but the bottom bit of code will.

```
function convertTemp2(degrees,unit) {
  if (unit === 'F' || unit === 'C') {
    conversion(degrees,unit);
    console.log(`${degrees} ${unit}`)
  } else {
    console.log('please use C for celcius, and F for fahrenheit');
  }
}

function conversion(degrees,unit) {
  if (unit === 'F') {
    degrees = (degrees+32) *5/9;
    unit = 'C';
    return degrees, unit;
  } else if (unit === 'C') {
    degrees = (degrees*9/5) + 32;
    unit = 'F';
    return degrees, unit;
  }
}

convertTemp2(1023,'F');
convertTemp2(12,'C');
convertTemp2(123,'H');
```

This seems to work:

```
function convertTemp2(degrees,unit) {
  if (unit === 'F' || unit === 'C') {
    conversion(degrees,unit);
  } else {
    console.log('please use C for celcius, and F for fahrenheit');
  }
}

function conversion(degrees,unit) {
  if (unit === 'F') {
    degrees = (degrees+32) *5/9;
    console.log(`${degrees}C`)
  } else if (unit === 'C') {
    degrees = (degrees*9/5) + 32;
    console.log(`${degrees}F`)
  }
}

convertTemp2(1023,'F');
convertTemp2(12,'C');
convertTemp2(123,'H');
```

Comment: _"I'm confused why the code below wont return or log anything on the console "_ The code you provided *does* log to the console.

Comment: You never use the returned values in `convertTemp2`. Notice, that function arguments are local to the function, they can't be seen or modified outside of the function despite of the same name. And also, a function can return a single value only, `return degrees, unit;` doesn't do what you think it does (it returns `unit` only).

Comment: oh right, it does I guess my question is why does the temperature not get converted before it gets logged to the console

Comment: oh okay i think i understand, even if i return the modified values, it still will not leave the ```conversion``` function scope?

Comment: Right. You've to return `{degrees, unit}` from `conversion`, and in `convertTemp2` assign the return value to a variable (ex. `res`). Then you can log `res.degrees` and `res.unit`.

Comment: thank you teemu, it looks like everyone agrees to return them as an object and then assign them to another variable. Then log them as that returned object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should look like

```js
function convertTemp2(degrees,unit) {
  if (unit === 'F' || unit === 'C') {
    const {a, b} = conversion(degrees,unit);
    console.log(`${a} ${b}`)
  } else {
    console.log('please use C for celcius, and F for fahrenheit');
  }
}

function conversion(degrees,unit) {
  let a, b
  if (unit === 'F') {
    a = (degrees+32) *5/9;
    b = 'C';
    return {a,b};
  } else if (unit === 'C') {
    a = (degrees*9/5) + 32;
    b = 'F';
    return {a, b};
  }
}

convertTemp2(1023,'F');
// convertTemp2(12,'C');
// convertTemp2(123,'H');
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful aswell, So you are returning an object instead of variable, and then saving them in the first function!

Comment: @BruceFerreira Technically an object *is* a variable

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your **first code snippet** lies in the way you're using the `return` statement in your **conversion function**.

In JavaScript, the return statement can only return a *single value*.

When you write `return degrees, unit;`, it doesn't actually return both `degrees` and `unit` as separate values.

Instead, it evaluates `degrees, unit` as an expression and returns only the value of `unit`.

To fix this issue, you could modify your `conversion` function to return an ***object*** containing both `degrees` and `unit`:

```
function conversion(degrees, unit) {
  if (unit === 'F') {
    degrees = (degrees + 32) * 5 / 9;
    unit = 'C';
    return { degrees, unit }; // return an object
  } else if (unit === 'C') {
    degrees = (degrees * 9 / 5) + 32;
    unit = 'F';
    return { degrees, unit }; // return an object
  }
}
```

And then, in your `convertTemp2` function, you can **extract** the values from the returned object and use them:

```
function convertTemp2(degrees, unit) {
  if (unit === 'F' || unit === 'C') {
    const result = conversion(degrees, unit); // extract the values
    console.log(`${result.degrees} ${result.unit}`);
  } else {
    console.log('please use C for celcius, and F for fahrenheit');
  }
}
```

You can preserve both values and use them correctly in your `convertTemp2` function.

And for your second code snippet it works because it directly logs the converted temperature and unit within the conversion function, without the need for returning any values.

Comment: oh wow! thats really cool thank u for the help! I was going to learn about objects today so i think thats neat